# Duda con código Python para leer archivos XML

Tags: python, xml

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer lectura de documento xml con Python y durante el proceso me encontré con un problema (duda).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET #as (alias)
data = '''<person>
  <name>Chuck</name>
  <phone type="intl">
    + 1 734 303 4456
  </phone>
   <email hide="yes"/>
</person>''' #cadena de tres comillas -> cadena multilínea

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print("Name:",tree.find("name").text) #buscar el nombre de la etiqueta
print("Attr:",tree.find("email").get("hide")) #get -> acceder a atributos
```

...

```
input = '''<stuff>
<users>
    <user x="2">
        <id>001</id>
        <name>Chuck</name>
    </user>
    <user x="7">
        <id>009</id>
        <name>Brent</name>
    </user>
</users>
</stuff>'''

stuff = ET.fromstring(input)
lst = stuff.findall("users/user")
print("User count:",len(lst))

for item in lst:
   print("Name:",item.find("name").text)
   print("Id:",item.find("id").text)
   print("Attribute:",item.get("x")) #no necesita find porque ya conocemos la etiqueta
```

En el primer código para poder obtener el atributo primero se usa el método `.find()` y luego el método `.get()`, mientras que en el segundo solo `.get()`. Probé solo poner el método `.get()` en el primer ejemplo, pero no funcionó, devuelve `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero hay que entender que hace cada método:

- El método `elemento.get(key, default=None)` (`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get`) obtiene el valor del atributo *key* del elemento o el valor de *default* si no se encuentra ese atributo en el mismo.
- El método `elemento.find(match, namespaces=None)` (`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find`) busca el primer sub-elemento hijo que coincide con *match*, retornando una instancia del mismo o `None` si no se encuentra.

Por tanto, `get` obtiene el valor del atributo del elemento en si y `find` busca un sub-elemento hijo del elemento. Por lo que

```
tree.find("email").get("hide")
```

retornara el valor del atributo *"hide"* del primer sub-elemento hijo del elemento `tree` con la etiqueta `"email"` que encuentre.

Si haces simplemente:

```
tree.get("hide")
```

buscara el atributo *"hide"* en el elemento `tree` directamente y no en uno de sus hijos, que no existe, por lo que retorna `None` por defecto.

En el segundo ejemplo, la clave esta en que **estas iterando con un `for` sobre cada uno de los sub-elementos hijos de `lst`**. Seria similar a hacer lo siguiente en el primer ejemplo:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = '''<person>
  <name>Chuck</name>
  <phone type="intl">
    + 1 734 303 4456
  </phone>
   <email hide="yes"/>
</person>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

for item in tree:
    if item.tag == "email":
        break    # find solo retorna la primera coincidencia
else:
    item = None  # Si no existe un sub-elemento con la etiqueta "email"
print(f'Attr: {item.get("hide")}')
```

en el que el ciclo `for` hace el trabajo de `find`, buscar el primer hijo de `tree` con la etiqueta *"email"*.

---

**Nota**: la linea del `else` no esta mal identada, no es un `if-else` es un `for-else`, la clausula `else` se ejecuta solo si el `for` se ha completado, es decir, sin invocar el `break`.